# What is Is the difference in SP metadata file when it uses self signed and CA issued cert

Tags: spring-saml

We have a SAML setup which uses a self-signed cert on a SP metadata file but when I change it to a CA issued cert, spring SAML complains that it cannot recognize the algorithm of the signing certificate. So I would like to know if the format of the SP metadata file itself would change? also should we also do any changes to the securityContext.xml in spring setup?

I have the CA issued cert imported into the keystore successfully. As part of the extended metadata I do mention the correct signing and encrypting alias to be used.

Excerpt of the changes to the SP metadata file I tried
...
zev7iEYUkjO8ESb+sm+kmcsoXzF6r8ddVAR03+DWoca8jJWm+6Gh2NNffnM4yXJa
mbGgiPpC2nyThvDCHIj2J32p
            
            
                CN=GeoTrust SSL CA, O="GeoTrust, Inc.", C=US
            
            CN=mydmainname.com,
                O=company, L=New York, ST=New York, C=US,
                SERIALNUMBER=1234

Please see the exception below

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.opensaml.ws.message.encoder.MessageEncodingException: The signing credential's algor
ithm URI could not be derived
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.commence(SAMLEntryPoint.java:164)
    at com.mae.service.saml.SAMLEngine.sendAuthenticationRequest(SAMLEngine.java:45)
    at com.mae.frontend.action.saml.SAMLRequestAction.execute(SAMLRequestAction.java:69)
    at com.mae.frontend.framework.request.Action._processAction(Action.java:94)
    at com.mae.frontend.framework.request.Action.processAction(Action.java:74)
    at com.mae.frontend.framework.request.ControllerServlet._doPost(ControllerServlet.java:175)
    at com.mae.frontend.framework.request.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:107)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.mae.perf.web.filter.HttpCompressionFilter._doFilter(HttpCompressionFilter.java:62)
    at com.mae.perf.web.filter.HttpCompressionFilter.doFilter(HttpCompressionFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.mae.i18n.ILContextFilter.doFilter(ILContextFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.mae.pmon.xt.http.HttpCallFilter._doFilter(HttpCallFilter.java:54)
    at com.mae.pmon.xt.http.HttpCallFilter.doFilter(HttpCallFilter.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.opensaml.ws.message.encoder.MessageEncodingException: The signing credential's algorithm URI could not be
 derived
    at org.opensaml.saml2.binding.encoding.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder.getSignatureAlgorithmURI(HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder.j
ava:223)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.binding.encoding.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder.buildRedirectURL(HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder.java:188)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.binding.encoding.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder.doEncode(HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder.java:104)
    at org.opensaml.ws.message.encoder.BaseMessageEncoder.encode(BaseMessageEncoder.java:52)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.sendMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:224)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.sendMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.sendMessage(AbstractProfileBase.java:148)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl.sendAuthenticationRequest(WebSSOProfileImpl.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.initializeSSO(SAMLEntryPoint.java:226)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.commence(SAMLEntryPoint.java:153)
    ... 31 more
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)? Can you update the post with the exception Spring SAML fails with once you use the CA-issued certificate?

Yes, the SP metadata would change - the public certificate is included in the metadata by default and it would correspond to the new one.

When changing the private key you need to update your springSecurity.xml to include alias of the new key in the key manager bean. You can find some more details on key management in the key management chapter of the [manual](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-key-management).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @VladimírSchäfer, I have not installed the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files will look it up. Yes I did add the alias key to the key manager.

Comment: Also, please enable debug logging (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-integration.html#logging) and update the question with the result after reproducing the problem.